# Spatial Null Models for Volumetric Data with the neuromaps toolbox

Tags: python, null

I want to calculate spatial nulls for my volumetric data (4D fMRI brain scans, NIfTI files). I have been using the neuromaps null models (as described here: https://netneurolab.github.io/neuromaps/user_guide/nulls.html), in this case the burt.2018() function.

However, I keep getting memory errors due to insufficient storage space. The documentation states a high computational intensity for those functions, but even running the code on high-performance computers returns this error.

Has anyone used the neuromaps null models before and can provide an estimate of the storage space utilized for these calculations, or any tips on how to minimize the computational intensity of this analysis?

The error is shown here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/ghrelin/tvns_neuromaps/spatial_nulls.py", line 51, in <module>
    nulls = nulls.burt2018(combined_mask_img, atlas='MNI152', density='3mm', n_perm=3, seed=1234)
  File "/home/neuromadlab/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/neuromaps/nulls/nulls.py", line 600, in burt2018
    return _make_surrogates(data, 'burt2018', atlas=atlas, density=density,
  File "/home/neuromadlab/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/neuromaps/nulls/nulls.py", line 537, in _make_surrogates
    hdist, np.argsort(hind, axis=-1), axis=-1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in argsort
  File "/home/neuromadlab/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 1146, in argsort
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'argsort', axis=axis, kind=kind, order=order)
  File "/home/neuromadlab/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 57, in _wrapfunc
    return bound(*args, **kwds)
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 243. GiB for an array with shape (180671, 180671) and data type int64
```

I have tried to reduce the data from int64 to int32 beforehand, but I still got an memory error.